# Pivot table using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I am getting count issue in the pivot table query using the SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Example**:

I have a table `testrf`:

```
 CREATE TABLE testrf
 (
   cola INTEGER,
   colb VARCHAR(10)
 )
```

With some data:

```
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'x')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(1,'x')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(2,'x')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(3,'y')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(4,'y')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(5,'c')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(6,'c')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(7,'c')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(8,'d')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(3,'y')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(12,'M1')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(13,'L1')
 INSERT INTO testrf VALUES(14,'C2')
```

Looks like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM testrf;

 cola   colb
 ------------
  1     x
  1     x
  2     x
  3     y
  4     y
  5     c
  6     c
  7     c
  8     d
  3     y
 12     M1
 13     L1
 14     C2
```

My Pivot table query:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF ( (SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + v.colb                        
               FROM testrf AS v                                         
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + ']'   


SET @SQL = N'SELECT cola,'+ @cols +'
   FROM                     
   (SELECT  v.cola,v.colb
       FROM testrf AS v                                   
       GROUP BY v.cola,v.colb                   
    ) p                     
       PIVOT                
           (            
               count(colb)                        
               FOR colb IN ( '+ @cols + ' )                        
           ) AS pvt';      

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Getting Result:

```
cola   c    C2  d   L1  M1  x   y
----------------------------------
1      0    0   0   0   0   1   0
2      0    0   0   0   0   1   0
3      0    0   0   0   0   0   1
4      0    0   0   0   0   0   1
5      1    0   0   0   0   0   0
6      1    0   0   0   0   0   0
7      1    0   0   0   0   0   0
8      0    0   1   0   0   0   0
12     0    0   0   0   1   0   0
13     0    0   0   1   0   0   0
14     0    1   0   0   0   0   0
```

**Note**: `colb=x` is occurred 2 times for `cola=1`and `colb=y` occurred 2 times for `cola=3`. Getting counting issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require the GROUP BY clause within the inner subquery (p)

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF ( (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(v.colb)
               FROM testrf AS v
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')


SET @SQL = N'SELECT cola,'+ @cols +'
   FROM
   (SELECT  v.cola,v.colb
       FROM testrf AS v
    ) p
       PIVOT
           (
               count(colb)
               FOR colb IN ( '+ @cols + ' )
           ) AS pvt'

EXEC(@SQL)
;
```

I have also proposed a change to your @cols by using QUOTENAME()

From your sample data this produces the following result:

```
| COLA | C | C2 | D | L1 | M1 | X | Y |
|------|---|----|---|----|----|---|---|
|    1 | 0 |  0 | 0 |  0 |  0 | 2 | 0 |
|    2 | 0 |  0 | 0 |  0 |  0 | 1 | 0 |
|    3 | 0 |  0 | 0 |  0 |  0 | 0 | 2 |
|    4 | 0 |  0 | 0 |  0 |  0 | 0 | 1 |
|    5 | 1 |  0 | 0 |  0 |  0 | 0 | 0 |
|    6 | 1 |  0 | 0 |  0 |  0 | 0 | 0 |
|    7 | 1 |  0 | 0 |  0 |  0 | 0 | 0 |
|    8 | 0 |  0 | 1 |  0 |  0 | 0 | 0 |
|   12 | 0 |  0 | 0 |  0 |  1 | 0 | 0 |
|   13 | 0 |  0 | 0 |  1 |  0 | 0 | 0 |
|   14 | 0 |  1 | 0 |  0 |  0 | 0 | 0 |
```

<kbd>[See this at SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4f91/1)</kbd>